# How to assemble a string of wide characters with some null ones inserted in the middle of it?

Tags: c++, windows, odbc, wstring

Let's start with the background. I need to set a string of attributes for an ODBC command:

```
SQLConfigDataSource(hwndParent, ODBC_ADD_DSN, sDriver, wcAttrs);
```

The attributes have to be formatted in a strict way to work:

```
LPCWSTR wcAttrs = L"DSN=NiceDB\0DBQ=C:\\Users\\who\\AppData\\Local\\NiceApp\\niceDB.accdb\0";
```

Hard coding it this way is working, but I actually need to dynamically set the path of the accdb file (DBQ). The issue are the required null characters separating the attributes in the string, and my string-fu skills mainly using **wcscat_s** fail because the null characters makes anything disappear after it.

What would be the best technique to assemble/concatenate strings with those null characters in the middle ?

Comment: std::string fully supports embedded null (or any other) characters.

Comment: Is the question exclusive to windows ?

Comment: You are the one asking the question, not me, so you should know. The  features of std::string are standardised.

Comment: Yes but someone added the windows tag. While ODBC is tied to windows, I just mentioned it for illustration purpose, not to be the main topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `push_back` a null char into a std::wstring as you build it.

Example:

```
std::wstring str;
str += L"DSN=NiceDB";
str.push_back(L'\0');
str += L"DBQ=C:\\Users\\who\\AppData\\Local\\NiceApp\\niceDB.accdb";
str.push_back(L'\0');
```

You can also manually append the null char using the += operator:

```
std::wstring str;
str += L"DSN=NiceDB";
str += L'\0';
str += L"DBQ=C:\\Users\\who\\AppData\\Local\\NiceApp\\niceDB.accdb";
str += L'\0';
```

You can also just tell the append method to use +1 characters of the string literal. That will implicitly pad the std::string with the null char already in the source:

```
std::wstring str;
const wchar_t* header = L"DSN=NiceDB";
const wchar_t* footer = L"DBQ=C:\\Users\\who\\AppData\\Local\\NiceApp\\niceDB.accdb";

str.append(header, wcslen(header) + 1);
str.append(footer, wcslen(footer) + 1);
```

Then to get the pointer to the start of the final string:

```
LPCWSTR wcAttrs = str.c_str();
```

The validity of the pointer returned by `.c_str()` is only good for the lifetime of the backing wstring. Don't let the wstring instance go out of scope while there's still something referencing wcAttrs.

Comment: Why in str.push_back(L'\0'); double quotes don't work ?

Comment: Because `(w)string::push_back` only accepts chars, not strings.

Comment: That, and a literal C-string of the form `"\0"` is no different than an empty string `""`. So any attempt to append an empty string is going to get treated as a no-op.  That's why `append(L"\0");` is a no-op. But it knows to treat `push_back(L'\0')` as an append of a null char

Comment: mmm, I still get an exception error. Does the c_str() command truncate the string to the first null char too ?

Comment: "Does the c_str() command truncate the string to the first null char too ?" - no, it doesn't, but any functions like strlen() that expect a single null-terminator will appear to do so. But SQLConfigDataSource is not such a function - it expects to see multiple null characters in the attribute  string.

Comment: You are allowing the lifetime of the `std::wstring` to be around longer than the usage of the value returned from `.c_str()`, right?  The validity and lifetime of the pointer returned by c_str() is only as good as the lifetime of the wstring instance backing it up. Don't let the wstring go out of scope while still using the pointer.

Comment: Yes. However actually it works, the exception comes from another unidentified issue in my code. Anyway the part to create that string is working and this answers my question.

Comment: Note, you can also use `operator+=` with single chars, eg `str += L'\0';`